# Can HR deny an upgrade after approval has been given?

Tags: promotion

I was on a contract for 4 years and during my contract period I was doing more than my pay grade. An approval was given for me to be made permanent and also be upgraded to a higher position to reflect my duties. I have been made permanent and upgraded but I was given a lower grade, instead of the approved Job requisition.

What should I do? Can I petition the HR on the issue?

Comment: Have you signed a contract for your permanent position and if so what did it say?

Comment: Please provide details of the given HR "grade", and the grade of "permanent position"

Comment: This isn't something we can answer, as it would be specific to your organization ... where apparently the answer is "Yes". Thus, I'm going to vote to close. It's nothing personal, and I hope you continue to visit the site and get help from it.

Comment: "i have been made permanent and upgraded but i was given a lower grade" - this part is confusing. If they upgraded you, what do you mean by a "lower grade"? Do you mean your salary?

Comment: When you take a job, which is also the case if you change from contractor to a permanent position, you sign a contract. If the contract was for the current pay grade, you don't petition HR to change it. If it was for a higher pay grade, you also don't "petition" HR, you simply tell them to honor the contract. If you were promised to get a raise (with no ifs or buts), but don't have it in writing, get that promise in writing - in the unlikely case that you manage to do so, you can then ask HR to honor that promise, which is also a contract.

Answer (score 3):

I would take this to your boss and make the assumption that it was done in error and ask him to clear it up.